# how can I create a dump carousel in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, carousel, material-ui

Please,
I want to know how to create a dump carousel in material-ui (for 3 images) since it's not predefined in material-ui ? I tried to use material-auto-rotating-carousel but it seems not easy to integrate in a simple React page.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, this feature doesn't exist in material-ui,
I will suggest to use some util for carousel
or you can use a util which provide a scrollable effect. Please check this answer - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/372089/carousel-no-material-ui